# Need help getting system to read fields from Form2 C#

Tags: c#, winforms, forms

I am creating a small program that speaks and can do minor tasks for me. I want to create a second form (Form2) in which I will type in my name and other personal info.

How can I get Form1 to read the textfields in Form2?

Comment: Create global variables?

Answer (score 3):

> How can I get Form1 to read the textfields in Form2?

Presumably `Form1` creates an instance of `Form2`... so hold on to that instance, and expose appropriate properties on the form:

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
form2.Show(); // Or ShowDialog?

string name = form2.UserName;
```

The implementation of `UserName` may well just fetch the value from the text field:

```
public string UserName { get { return userNameTextField.Text; } }
```

You *could* expose the text field directly with a property, but personally I tend to think that a form should "own" its UI, and not let other code mess with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create Methods and form1 to retreive the data from `textfields`

```
public string GetTextFieldText()
{
     return textfield.Text;
}
```

Or wrap it with an property

```
public string TextField
{
    get
    {
        return textfield.Text;
    }
}
```

Then access it from form2 something like this:

```
Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
string text = frm1.TextField; // Or GetTextFieldText()
```

Answer (score 0):

Create global variables with modifier `public` and then assign the text of the textboxes to the variables either using `Text_Changed` event or `button_click` event (if you want to retrieve text after button click.

Then in your `Form1`. You use

```
    Form2 form = new Form2();
    //Then do whatever u want with the variable
    MessageBox.Show(form.globalVariableName);
```

**or**

Set the modifier property of the textbox to `public` in your `form2` and in your `Form1`

```
    Form2 form = new Form2();
    //Then do whatever u want with the textbox
    MessageBox.Show(form.TextBoxName.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started:

```
//Global Variable
Form2 frm2;

//assuming form1 is the creator of form2
public Form1()
{
   frm2 = new Form2();
}

//in your Form1, under read data button for example:
string myName = frm2.TextBox1.Text;
```